# Problemas com SQLitePlugin Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: android, apache-cordova, sqlite3

Estou tentando criar uma conexão com um banco de dados SQLite criado dentro da minha aplicação e retorna o seguinte erro.

```
SQLitePlugin.executeSql[Batch](): Error=no such table: fornecedor_motorista (code 1): ,
while compiling: INSERT INTO fornecedor_motorista 
(id_fornecedor,nome,email,telefone,celular,cnh,validade,usuario,senha,created_at) VALUES
(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Esse erro ocorre na seguinte linha de código...

Arquivo: navigation.js # Incluido no index.html

```
$(this).on('click','.submit_login',function(){
    var usuario = $('.login').val();
    var senha   = $('.senha').val();
    $.getJSON(
        "<minha-api>", 
        function(data){
            teste.innerHTML = data.nome;

            var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "meu-db.db"});

            db.transaction(function(tx){
                tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO fornecedor_motorista (id_fornecedor,nome,email,telefone,celular,cnh,validade,usuario,senha,created_at) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                            [data.id_fornecedor,data.nome,data.email,data.telefone,data.celular,data.cnh,data.validade,data.usuario,data.senha,'0000-00-00 00:00:00'],function(tx,res){
                                teste.innerHTML="Os dados foram inseridos com sucesso";
                });
            });
        }
    );
});
```

---

Fiz os testes, coloquei a inclusão da tabela diretamente no arquivo index.js e chamei ela no onDeviceReady, no caso a conexão e a criação das tabelas, mas o erro persiste...

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

    var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "4routes.db"});

    db.transaction(function(tx){
        $('#teste').append("A conexão foi criada.<br>");
        /* Minhas tabelas... */
        tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fornecedor_motorista (id_motorista INT(11) primary key,id_fornecedor INT(11),nome VACHAR(60),email VARCHAR(255),telefone VARCHAR(20),celular VARCHAR(20), cnh VARCHAR(20), validade VARCHAR(10),usuario VARCHAR(20), senha VARCHAR(100), created_at DATETIME)");

        tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS persistencia (id INT(11) primary key, id_motorista int(11),ativo TINYINT(1), created_at DATETIME);");

        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM fornecedor_motorista",[],function(tx,res){
            $('#teste').append("Conseguimos realizar uma consulta<br>");
            $(res).each(function(){
                console.log();
                $("#teste").append($(this));
            });

        });
    });
},
```

Esses textos aparecem, porém, quando eu faço a inclusão dos dados num outro arquivo, sendo ele um que dei o nome de navigation.js que é o que possui a query acima, dá o mesmo erro conforme a questão acima...

Acrescentando mais algumas informações adicionais.

`1. O banco de dados foi criado dentro de assets/www`

`2. A aplicação aparentemente abre a conexão, pois não retorna erro e as mensagens que eu coloco dentro de db.transactions retornam normalmente`

`3. Ocorre o retorno do JSON do servidor`

`4. Aparece a mensagem dizendo que os dados foram inseridos com sucesso, porém, quando coloco uma consulta logo abaixo pra retornar os dados, não retorna nada.`

Comment: Ewerton, como é feita a criação das tabelas?

Comment: Fiz diretamente pelo terminal.

Comment: Só um complemento, os dados q precisam ser recuperados por JSON, são recuperados normalmente, eu tenho o JSON retornado do Servidor normalmente, porém, o problema está na gravação dos dados no DB SQLite...

Comment: Não conheço o PhoneGap, mas o problema de fato é que no dispositivo que esta testando, não foram criadas as tabelas. Ou então ele está tentando inserir em um banco diferente do qual criou as tabelas pelo terminal. As tabelas não deveriam ser criadas dentro do código? Assim quando essa app for instalado as tabelas serão criadas automaticamente.

Comment: Entendi... Vou fazer a criação delas pelo PhoneGap diretamente... Já posto uma resposta.

Comment: Deixei uma resposta com a alteração q fiz...

Comment: Complementei mais algumas coisas sobre o problema.

Comment: Ewerton, não tenho muita idéia do que possa ser, como eu disse não costumo usar o PhoneGap. O fato de nos dois arquivos você referenciar bancos diferentes, é erro de cópia ou esta assim mesmo em seu aplicativo?

Comment: Então, resolvi o problema trocando pro Storage... Como a aplicação não é grande, creio que o Storage resolva o problema.

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.